# how to write xpath for getting h4 , h5 and span in selenium c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-2.0

```
<div class="card-header bg-info">
<h4>Dumpytext</h4> 
<h5> Dump text/ mg 
<span style="font-size: 0.9rem;">(100mg/ 50mg)</span> 
</h5>
</div>
```

I want to hit the h5 and span data in selenium c# and xpath without index

Comment: Add the code and `HTML` source

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.findElement(By.Xpath(//h5));`
and `driver.findElement(By.Xpath(//h5));`

Comment: Both your XPath expressions are trying to locate same node `h5`. Also, the XPath expression should be enclosed within quotes `"//h5"`

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="card-header bg-info">
    <h4>Dumpytext</h4> 
    <h5> Dump text/ mg 
        <span style="font-size: 0.9rem;">(100mg/ 50mg)</span> 
    </h5>
</div>
```

To print the text from `<h4>`, `<h5>` and `<span>` tags you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *XPath* for `<h4>` tag:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h4")).Text);
  ```
- *XPath* for `<h5>` tag:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h5")).Text);
  ```
- *XPath* for `<span>` tag:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h5/span")).Text);
  ```